# PHP email image and form content

Tags: php

I have been trying to email myself the content of a form such as name, date, time etc which all work fine and I ge the email containing the information

The problem I have now is the user is allowed to upload an image and I want this image to be attched to the email but something is clearly wrong, when the image is attached the other fields are no longer attached to the email.

Heres my code with the attachement included:

```
 <?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $incidentDate = $_POST['date'];
    $incidentTime = $_POST['time'];
    $fullName = $_POST['name'];
    $additionalComments = $_POST['comments'];

    // File upload handling
    $fileToUpload = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

    // Prepare email message
    $to = "your_email@example.com";
    $subject = "Incident Report";
    $message = "Incident Date/Time: $incidentDate $incidentTime\n";
    $message .= "Full Name: $fullName\n";
    $message .= "Additional Comments: $additionalComments\n";

    // Set up headers for email
    $headers = "From: your_email@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: your_email@example.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

    // Prepare attachment
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileToUpload)));

    // Add the attachment to the email message
    $message .= "--PHP-mixed-" . $random_hash . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $fileName . "\"\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $attachment . "\r\n";

    $message = "Incident Date/Time: $incidentDate $incidentTime\n";
    $message .= "Full Name: $fullName\n";
    $message .= "Additional Comments: $additionalComments\n";
    
    // Send email
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // Redirect back to the form page
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
    exit();
}
?>
```

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Incident Date / Time</label>
        <input id="date" class="form-control" type="date" name="date" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="cs-form">
        <input type="time" class="form-control" value="10:05 AM" name="time" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="" name="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Additional Comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" name="comments"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Upload Incident Images</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" name="image">

      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated to help me understand the attachment impact on the email sending with both the attachment and the form content

Comment: Spare yourself the headache and use something like PhpMailer to construct the email and format the attachment data into it correctly for you. Then, adding an attachment is just a one-line function call from your point of view. Getting it right yourself is fiddly, frustrating, and unnecessary